# Should I follow the WHATWG HTML Living Standard?

Tags: html, standards

I'm reading up on the [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) element on MDN. Currently, it says the following:

> ***Note***: `<main>` must not be a descendent of an `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` element.
>
> *Authors must not include more than one main element in a document.*

This reflects the HTML5 Proposed Recommendation and the HTML5.1 Working Draft. But the Living Standard reverses these two rules. It says:

> *There is no restriction as to the number of `main` elements in a document. Indeed, there are many cases where it would make sense to
>   have multiple main elements. For example, a page with multiple article
>   elements might need to indicate the dominant contents of each such
>   element.*

As well as not having any restriction on the parent elements. Which standard should I follow?

Comment: In addition to being opinion-based, the question calls for discussion on a topic where the choice has no practical impact beyond the coding style.

Comment: Take your pick. The issue is discussed in the comments of [HTML Doctor - The Main Element](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/) with Ian Hickson explaining his justification for the WHATWG requirement and Steve Faulkner giving the W3C case. As I comment there, the WHATWG justification does not seem consistent with its requirements - and its requirements may be genuinely problematic for accessibility technology users.

Answer (score 3):

From what I have read the `<main>` element helps group the main or most important part of your content. This is useful for screen readers to asses what's important for the user.

Id be inclined to go with the MDN recommendation of using only one `<main>` element surrounding your main content. If screen readers and other accessibility tools start to widely use the main content as a source of the important information you would be covered on that front.

**Update:** Taking a further look into this it appears the W3C validator will throw an error if you use more than one `<main>` element. More information can be found here: http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/